# Converting empty string to nil via split()

Tags: ruby, split, string

I've got a string that I'm splitting, as follows:

```
foo, bar, baz, etc = str.split(',')
```

If, for example, `str` is equal to "one,two,,four", then `baz` ends up equalling "" (an empty string).  Is there any easy way to loop through these for parameters to convert them to `nil` if they're an empty string?  Or am I stuck doing the following?

```
foo = nil if foo.blank?
bar = nil if bar.blank?
baz = nil if baz.blank?
etc = nil if etc.blank?
```

Comment: why do you need it to be nil?

Comment: Because nil and empty string are two different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing this in rails, you can use the Object#presence method:

```
foo, bar, baz, etc = str.split(',').map(&:presence)
```

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest you this solution:

```
foo, bar, baz, etc = str.split(',').map{|ss| ss.blank? ? nil : ss}
```